# php convert string variable to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have string and need convert to array.

```
<?php
$str = '"en"=>"English" , "fr"=>"French" , "de"=>"German"';
$array = array($str);
print_r($array)
?>
```

I need this result:

```
Array
(
    [en] => English
    [fr] => French
    [de] => German
)
```

Is there a function in PHP to do this?

when try below code, I get good result.but when use uppern code, NO! How to convert String variable for input array?

```
<?php
//$str = '"en"=>"English" , "fr"=>"French" , "de"=>"German"';
$array = array("en"=>"English" , "fr"=>"French" , "de"=>"German");
print_r($array)
?>
```

Comment: That looks like an associative array. The evil `eval` comes to mind. _Don't_ do it. Instead try a series of `explode` and `trim` or even `preg_match`.

Comment: No, this is not a generally supported serialisation format. You'll have to write your own function for this custom format. Or use something that is generally supported, like JSON.

Comment: Where does this come from? How did it end up being a String in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval, In your case could be something like this:

```
$str = '"en"=>"English" , "fr"=>"French" , "de"=>"German"';
eval("\$array = array($str);");
print_r($array)
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [en] => English
    [fr] => French
    [de] => German
)
```

Comment: Thank YOU!this is a BEST answer for me.I need this!Like!

Comment: @putvande  my $str variable is not user input and generated by php. Yes, if use `eval` for user input, maybe occured security bug.

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, you should probably look in to `json` if you have a way of changing the string, else something like this will suffice:

```
$str = '"en"=>"English" , "fr"=>"French" , "de"=>"German"';
$first = explode(' , ',$str);

$second = array();
foreach($first as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $item);
    $second[str_replace('"', '', $key)] = $value;
}
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [en] => "English"
    [fr] => "French"
    [de] => "German"
)
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/166011)

Comment: I would remove the quotes from the keys. Otherwise you will have to access them with `$second["\"fr\""];`